# Showing a meta box in a custom post type on a page

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox

I have a problem. I'm trying to add a meta box textarea field to a custom post type (in a plugin) with custom database table. The meta box is displaying in the custom post type, saving and updating, but just not showing the data on a page (front end) and I just can't figure it out. It shows the title and content of the post, but not the entered data. 
Here is my code for meta box:

```
    //show metabox in post editing page
    add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'bsp_add_metabox' );

    function bsp_add_metabox() {
   // add_meta_box( $id, $title, $callback, $screen, $context, $priority );
  add_meta_box('bsp_mother_tongue', 'Mother language','bsp_mother_tongue_handler', 'badge','normal');
   }
   //showing the meta box on admin page
  function bsp_mother_tongue_handler($post){

$value = get_post_custom($post->ID);
?>
<!--<label for="bsp_text_meta">Mother language </label><br />-->
<textarea id="bsp_text_meta" name="bsp_text_meta" class="widefat" style="overflow:auto; resize:none" rows="15"><?php if(isset($value['bsp_text_meta'])) {echo $value['bsp_text_meta'][0]; } ?></textarea>
```

```
//check if user can edit post
if( !current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) ) {
    return;  
}

if( isset($_POST['bsp_text_meta'] )) {
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'bsp_text_meta', esc_attr($_POST['bsp_text_meta']));
}
}
```

badge is the name of a custom post type (slug).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using multiple key & values, I'd try it this way

```
// This function adds a meta box with a callback function of my_metabox_callback()
function add_my_meta_box() {
     $var1 = 'this';
     $var2 = 'that';
     add_meta_box( 
           'metabox_id',
           'Metabox Title',
           'my_metabox_callback',
           'page',
           'normal',
           'low', 
           array( 'foo' => $var1, 'bar' => $var2)
      );
}

// $post is an object containing the current post (as a $post object)
// $metabox is an array with metabox id, title, callback, and args elements. 
// The args element is an array containing your passed $callback_args variables.

function my_metabox_callback ( $post, $metabox ) {
     echo 'Last Modified: ' . $post->post_modified;        // outputs last time the post was modified
     echo $metabox['args']['foo'];                         // outputs 'this'
     echo $metabox['args']['bar'];                         // outputs 'that'
     echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_custom_field', true ); // outputs value of custom field
}
```

Also you can use the_content filter to add anything to single.php

Example code:

```
function tsi_source_link($content) {
 if ( is_single() ) {
   global $post;
   $source_link = get_post_meta ($post->ID, 'syndication_permalink', true);
   if ($source_link) {
    $content .= '<div id="tsi-source-link" style="text-align:right;"><a href="' . $source_link . '" target="_blank">Read more ...</a></div>';
}
}
return $content;
}
add_action('the_content','tsi_source_link');
```

Comment: Hi @Wali, this also does not work. I found a temporary solution to add a code 
`$meta_value = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'bsp_meta-text', true ); if( !empty( $meta_value ) ) {echo $meta_value; }`

into themes single.php But because it's a plugin it's not a good idea.

Comment: I am not sure why this won't work or is not a good idea if in Plugin? Can you share please?

Comment: This bit of code is now manually added to the themes single.php. If it's a plugin I can't do that, because I don't know which themw the user has. I somehow need to add the code from a plugin to the theme's single.php but I don't know how to do that. Or there is a better solution for showing the meta box on the front end. @wali

Comment: If I use the code you provided the metabox is not showing on the page. I think because when I click publish the post the meta box is empty, so that means it doesn't save the metabox whit your approach.

Comment: The code I gave you was for your reference on how to create metaboxes and get their value. I will edit my post with complete code.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was missing the part with the adding things to the single.php. I always forget about filters. I'm new to all this wp development. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad it worked for you.. If you're new to WP .. Hooks & filters are way to go and Codex is your best friend.